# why is: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(\sin(1/x) *(1/x))/(1/x) \neq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

For example:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2 * \sin(1/x)}{\sin(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x * \sin(1/x)}{1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x * \sin(1/x) *(1/x)}{1*(1/x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x * (1/x)}{1} = 1$$
It is wrong..
\sin(1/x) *

My question is why is: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(\sin(1/x) *(1/x))/(1/x) \neq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(1/x)$

Since we were thought at lectures that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$

Comment: Well $\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}$ does not tend to $1$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes exactly, why is that ?

Comment: Why should it do that? What is guaranteed is that $(\sin x) /x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$. If you replace $x$ by $1/x$ then replace it everywhere including $x\to 0$ to make it $1/x\to 0$ which means $x\to\infty$ (considering $x>0$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=\lim_{u\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}=0$$